# How to add/insert multiple TJsonArray's within each other and still maintain their 'names'?

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-2009

I have been searching for days, but I can't figure out how to add/insert `TJsonArray`s within each other, without them losing their property name.
In the following I need to set the names of 'subArray' and 'CompanyItemState._get_accessToInvoice' (an array of integer)

This is my code:

```
jsonObj := TJsonObject.Create;
  try
    ParamsObj := jsonObj.O['params'];
    ParamsObj.FromSimpleObject(SessionInfo, false);
    jsonObj['facadeClassName'] := 'dk.vs.int.IntFac';
    jsonObj['methodName']      := 'typesTest';
    argsObj                    := jsonObj.A['args'].AddObject;
    argsObj['aChar']           := input._get_aChar;
    argsObj['aString']         := input._get_aString;
    argsObj['aDouble']         := input._get_aDouble;
    argsObj['aInt']            := input._get_aInt;
    argsObj['aLong']           := input._get_aLong;
    argsObj['aBool']           := input._get_aBool;
    argsObj['aSpecialEnum']    := input._get_aSpecialEnum;
    argsObj['aEnum']           := input._get_aEnum;
    argsObj['aNotherEnum']     := input._get_aNotherEnum;
    argsObj['aBigEnum']        := input._get_aBigEnum;
    jsonaArray                 := argsObj.A['aArray'].AddArray;
    jsonaArray.Insert(0, dk_vs_int_IntFac_i.SupportedTypeSubStateArray(input._get_aArray)[0]._get_aSubString);
    subArray                   := jsonaArray.InsertArray(1);   // How to specify the name of this array ? 
for n := 0 to length(hasAccessToFolders) -1 do 
subArray.Insert(n, mapperStateArray(VirksomhedItemsStateArray(SupportedTypeSubStateArray(input._get_aArray)[0]._get_aSubArray)[0].hasAccessToFolders)[n]);
jsonaArray.Insert(2, CompanyItemState._get_accessToInvoice);
output := jsonObj.ToJSON({Compact:=}False);
finally
    jsonObj.Free;
end;
```

and the output is as follows:

```
{
    "params": {
        "weblognavn": "myweblognavn",
        "sessionid": "07.16.35",
        "kredsnr": 4,
        "Sysnr": 179,
        "ejdnr": 1000
    },
    "facadeClassName": "dk.vs.int.IntFac",
    "methodName": "typesTest",
    "args": [
        {
            "aChar": "c",
            "aString": "aString",
            "aDouble": 3.14159265358979,
            "aInt": 7,
            "aLong": 2147483647,
            "aBool": true,
            "aSpecialEnum": 0,
            "aEnum": 9,
            "aNotherEnum": 1,
            "aBigEnum": 32,
            "aArray": [
                [
                    "aSubString",
                    [
                        1,
                        2,
                        3
                    ],
                    false
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I might have got it all wrong, so any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How you produce yours JSON and how it looks like?

Comment: This is not valid JSON to begin with - you have to learn the difference between a JSON object and a JSON array.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. This is not the real output but just an example that I wrote in hand to illustrate my problem and I now realize that I missed a couple of brackets. Unfortunately our server is down for the moment, so I can't produce the actual output fot the moment but I will get back to you as soon as our servers are up and running again.

Comment: @Per Without seeing your actual code, we can't tell you why you are not getting the output you want. Please provide a [mcve] that is not working the way you want.

Comment: Sample code and output has been replaced by actual ones.